# How to hide GWT com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode application window?

Tags: java, gwt, ant, integration-testing

I have integration tests that start my GWT application using com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode class. The web server starts as expected but DevMode also pops out its graphic window. I would like to hide this windows as we may need to run these tests in the headless environment.

Is it possible to start com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode without its graphic window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could extend `DevMode` and call its `setHeadless` method. But you're not supposed to run integration tests in DevMode, you should run them in prod mode.

An alternative would be to provide a *remote UI* (this is what the Google Plugin for Eclipse uses to integrate DevMode into an Eclipse view), but it requires talking the *remote UI* protocol.